# How to change text color for back-quoted text in trello.com

Tags: trello

When I use back quote to highlight terms in trello card content, the outcome to be in red color which I don't like it.

I prefer to format it as we do back-quoting here e.g. `a back-quoted text sample`.

Is it possible to change that in trello.com ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of options:

1. Go to Settings and click *Enable Color Blind Friendly Mode* under *Accessibility*. This will give you the black on gray that you desire. It will change some other coloring as well. You'll notice that the label colors are now striped.
2. You can install a browser extension like *Stylish* and add a CSS rule for the `code` element to set the text color to black. Something like `code { color: black !important;}`